# Class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not found - Intellij (UI 14.141.1192.2)

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When compiling Gradle can't find **android.support.v4**, even though it is correctly declared in **build.gradle**.

I'm using the android-scala plugin which I don't think is the issue because various other posts seem to have the same issue. Intellij displays libraries under the sidebar: "project view", but at compile time the library "**android.support.v4**" is not available, also not after clean compile.
I have tried all suggestions I could find on StackOverflow but without success.

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Adam

**Error message:**

```
Error:scalac: Error: Class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LockMode not found
java.lang.AssertionError: Class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LockMode not found
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$enterOwnInnerClasses$1$$anonfun$12.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:1050)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$enterOwnInnerClasses$1.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:1049)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$enterOwnInnerClasses$1.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:1046)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2.foreach(HashMap.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.enterOwnInnerClasses(ClassfileParser.scala:1046)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:457)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:133)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:212)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1488)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala$tools$nsc$GlobalSymbolLoaders$$lookup$1(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders$$anonfun$lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible$1.apply(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders$$anonfun$lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible$1.apply(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders.lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$classfileParser$.lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible(SymbolLoaders.scala:320)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.getMember$1(ClassfileParser.scala:1140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.innerSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:1142)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.innerSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:1131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.classNameToSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:406)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getClassSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:225)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getSuperClass(ClassfileParser.scala:284)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseParents$1$1$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:431)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseParents$1$1$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:431)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseParents$1(ClassfileParser.scala:427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:453)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:133)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:212)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1488)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala$tools$nsc$GlobalSymbolLoaders$$lookup$1(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders$$anonfun$lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible$1.apply(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders$$anonfun$lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible$1.apply(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GlobalSymbolLoaders.lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible(GlobalSymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$classfileParser$.lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible(SymbolLoaders.scala:320)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.getMember$1(ClassfileParser.scala:1140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.innerSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:1142)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$innerClasses$.innerSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:1131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.classNameToSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:406)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getClassSymbol(ClassfileParser.scala:225)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getSuperClass(ClassfileParser.scala:284)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseParents$1$1$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:431)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseParents$1$1$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassfileParser.scala:431)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseParents$1(ClassfileParser.scala:427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:453)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:133)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:212)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.load(SymbolLoaders.scala:228)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.isStale(Typers.scala:496)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.reallyExists(Typers.scala:487)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$qualifies$1(Typers.scala:4841)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$105.apply(Typers.scala:4867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$105.apply(Typers.scala:4867)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.filter(Symbols.scala:1916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.lookupImport$1(Contexts.scala:1102)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.lookupSymbol(Contexts.scala:1123)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIdent$2(Typers.scala:4867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIdentOrWildcard$1(Typers.scala:4905)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5340)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeConstructor(Typers.scala:5532)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeConstructor(Typers.scala:5549)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedParentType(Typers.scala:1468)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedParentTypes(Typers.scala:1631)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.templateSig(Namers.scala:919)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.classSig(Namers.scala:968)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.getSig$1(Namers.scala:1523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Namers.scala:781)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Namers$Namer$$logAndValidate(Namers.scala:1568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:780)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:772)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.completeImpl(Namers.scala:1684)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter$class.complete(Namers.scala:1692)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.complete(Namers.scala:1682)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Kinds$$anonfun$checkKindBounds0$2.apply(Kinds.scala:215)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Kinds$$anonfun$checkKindBounds0$2.apply(Kinds.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections$class.flatMap2(Collections.scala:130)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.flatMap2(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Kinds$class.checkKindBounds0(Kinds.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.checkKindBounds0(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.checkKindBounds(Infer.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.check$1(Infer.scala:893)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.checkBounds(Infer.scala:898)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeApply(Typers.scala:3931)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeApply$1(Typers.scala:5149)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5320)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArg(Typers.scala:3163)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgWithFormal$1(PatternTypers.scala:112)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:46)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.map$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgsForFormals(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArgsForFormals(Typers.scala:111)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$handleMonomorphicCall$1(Typers.scala:3469)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.doTypedApply(Typers.scala:3494)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$95.apply(Typers.scala:4494)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$95.apply(Typers.scala:4494)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.tryTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4494)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4542)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedCase(Typers.scala:2421)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedCases$1.apply(Typers.scala:2440)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedCases$1.apply(Typers.scala:2439)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedCases(Typers.scala:2439)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMatch(Typers.scala:2451)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedVirtualizedMatch$1(Typers.scala:4309)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5322)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3046)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2381)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedCase(Typers.scala:2421)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedCases$1.apply(Typers.scala:2440)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedCases$1.apply(Typers.scala:2439)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedCases(Typers.scala:2439)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMatch(Typers.scala:2451)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedVirtualizedMatch$1(Typers.scala:4309)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5322)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5605)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2208)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5308)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3046)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1921)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1762)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5309)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3046)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3150)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5012)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5312)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5448)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:102)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:432)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:94)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:93)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.4"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "jp.leafytree.android-scala"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sniff_it.tlock.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            scala {
                srcDir "src/main/scala"
            }
        }

        androidTest {
            scala {
                srcDir "src/androidTest/scala"
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
        exclude "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6"
    compile "de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7"
    compile "de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0"
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
//    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1", { exclude module: "multidex" }
    //compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0"
    //compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0"
//    compile "de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:1.3.1"
//    compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3"
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    // If you want to use scala compile daemon
    scalaCompileOptions.useCompileDaemon = true
    // Suppress deprecation warnings
    //scalaCompileOptions.deprecation = false
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-feature"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android-Scala *is* the problem here. There's an [issue](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/173) at the sbt plugin project where the problem is discussed. For now you have to manually add the missing classes, but scala 2.11.7 will probably resolve the issue.

For now you can overcome this issue by adding the missing classes manually, e.g. with [this](https://github.com/taig/hello-scala/blob/ef63e3ebbe0dc25898cefab629b93a531c7744c2/libs/android-support-v4.jar) jar file as an unmanaged dependency.

**Update:** Scala 2.11.7 is out, but the problem still persists in a similar fashion. The updated jar can be found [here](https://github.com/Taig/Hello-Scala/blob/81ee5972968e852eefe9157c33a4606080ee420c/src/main/libs/android-support-v4.jar).